# How to exclude null values from column group to calculate StDev in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, stdev

I have to calculate StDev for my column groups. The problem is that it take in calculations null values.
I use this:

```
=IIF(Fields!estNumerique.Value = 0, "n/a",Replace( Format( StDev( cDec( Replace( IIF(Fields!estNumerique.Value = 0, nothing, Fields!result.Value) ,",",".")))   ,"0.000") ,".",","))
```

And I get this result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwX8Z.jpg)

I calculated Average wiht following method, but for StDev I cannnot find the solution:

```
=IIf(Fields!SomeField.Value = 0, 0, Fields!SomeOtherField.Value / IIf(Fields!SomeField.Value = 0, 1, Fields!SomeField.Value))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StDev` function ignores `NULL` values. You are doing good by converting the 0's to `NULL`. The problem is that your `CDec` function is changing the `NULL`'s back to 0. So just remove that.

EDIT:

Try this:

```
=IIF(Fields!estNumerique.Value = 0, "n/a",Replace( Format( StDev( Replace( IIF(Fields!estNumerique.Value = 0, Nothing, CDec(Fields!result.Value)) ,",","."))   ,"0.000") ,".",","))
```

Comment: Hello, StevenWhite, if I remove CDec, it return error : a numeric aggregate function on data that is not numeric. I get a string value in result and I have to decide if it is numeric or not. So, I have to have this Cdec in my expression. Can you propose an other solution?

Comment: Yeah, just move the `CDec` to be around the field name inside the `IIf` statement. That way it does the type conversion before ignoring the 0's.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case. As result, I have added a column in my query that returns only numerical value and I have changed my expression for:

=IIF(Fields!estNumerique.Value = 0, "n/a", Format(StDev(Fields!result_num.Value), "0.000"))

Comment: OK, glad we figured out the issue. Also, you may need to wrap a `Max` function around that first "Fields!estNumerique.Value". Otherwise, you will get "n/a" if the **First** value happens to be 0 but the others aren't.